# Error in adding arraylist items to Listview

Tags: java, android

```
         package com.example.admin.accountbook;

           import android.annotation.TargetApi;
          import android.icu.util.Calendar;
          import android.os.Build;
           import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
            import android.os.Bundle;
            import android.util.Log;
           import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
             import android.widget.ListView;
           import android.widget.Toast;

              import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
            import java.util.ArrayList;
              import java.util.Date;

          public class Dates extends AppCompatActivity {
             ListView dates;
          Date dte;
          ArrayList dt9 = new ArrayList();
          @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
          protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
          setContentView(R.layout.activity_dates);
          dates = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.dates);
          ArrayAdapter da =new ArrayAdapter
          (this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dt9);
          dates.setAdapter(da);
          Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
          SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");
          try {
              for (int a = 1; a <= 31; a++) 
               {
               calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                dte = calendar.getTime();
                dt9.add(formattedDate.format(dte));
                   da.notifyDataSetChanged();

             }

          }catch(Exception e)
           {
                 Log.e("output",e+"");
                }


          }
```

> I am Getting list of dates in to arraylist.But listview not 
>                  returning those dates.Listview populating only Yesterday's             date.Getting dates correctly in to arraylist. Please    help 
>                me.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Call `da.notifyDataSetChanged();` out of `for` loop.

Comment: I tried.but not working

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
try {
              for (int a = 1; a <= 31; a++) 
               {
               calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
                dte = calendar.getTime();
                dt9.add(formattedDate.format(dte));

             }

         ArrayAdapter da =new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dt9);
          dates.setAdapter(da)
  }
```

Setting the adapter again after getting data will solve your problem.

Comment: no  error in logcat.but when I try to display Listview in Toast ...it is giving me some msg like android.widget.listview[.......].Arraylist showing me all dates which i needed.

Comment: Share the complete message

Comment: Check the exception log, what is the message you are getting there

Comment: edited.....I need to get dates from 1st of current month to current date in oncreate method.

Comment: There is a problem in your calculation of getting days

Answer (score 0):

Set adapter again

```
try {
    for (int a = 1; a <= 31; a++) 
    {
        calendar.add(Calendar.DATE, -1);
        dte = calendar.getTime();
        dt9.add(formattedDate.format(dte));
    }
    ArrayAdapter da =new ArrayAdapter(this,R.layout.support_simple_spinner_dropdown_item,dt9);
    dates.setAdapter(da);

} catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.e("output",e+"");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display dates from first day of current month to current date, then you can try below code:

```
    Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
    Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();

    ArrayList<String> dt9 = new ArrayList<>();

    calendar1.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    SimpleDateFormat formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("d/M/yyyy");

    for (int i = 0; i < calendar2.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); i++) {
        Date date = calendar1.getTime();
        dt9.add(formattedDate.format(date));

        Log.d("kk", "onCreate: "+dt9.get(i));

        calendar1.add(Calendar.DATE, 1);

    }

     da.notifyDataSetChanged();
```